# How would you describe 'installing' an artificial arm for someone?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

I really can't think how write this.

> The moment the artificial limb was finished, they would help install it on the Old Madam.

That's the original and I know it doesn't sound right but I can't think how to make it sound right, the best I have at the moment is:

> The moment the artificial limb was finished, they would help set it up for the Old Madam.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: I would use the word "fit": "they would help fit it to the Old Madam".

Comment: Yes! Thanks, that works well, I was really struggling to think of the right word XD

Comment: Using the term "Old Madam" is diversionary - as the sentence already carries casual informality which is bound to affect the type of verb chosen. But if you change "Old Madam" to "the patient", I would go for "attach", and if I were allowed two words -  "surgically attach".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think I'll play around with the sentence later and see what sounds best :)

Comment: they would help the Old Madam to don it?

Comment: I would vote for 'fit' too. I'm sure it's the term I've seen used in that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as the artificial limb was finished, they would **join** it to the Old Madam.

The verb conveys the relationships that exist between the installers of the limb, the patient, the people who created the limb, and the limb itself.

*Fit* (already suggested) is good.  However, if you imagine a limb with advanced biological technology, possibly grown from the patient's own cellular specifications, the idea of *fitting* is no longer adequate.  Such a creation would not be fitted like a pair of eyeglasses.

But it really depends on what you are trying to describe.

Comment: Thanks, you've given me more to think about :)   
But, to me, joining seems like something you'd say when working with metal or a machine, not sure if it sounds quite right for a human. Thanks all the same :D